# Adding an upvote for googlers (and the like)

Tags: feature-request

Up-votes are directly linked to rep, which keep the stackexchange communities functioning properly. But for a Googler -or similar- who wishes to express their gratitude for the found answer, and who is not directly interested in rep and the like, could we have an extra "free as in no account needed" button that doesn't count towards any medals/rep/other prestigious quantity, but just says "thanks"?

For the author and answerer it is nice to see people appreciate their efforts. At the same time, there is absolutely no incentive for a visitor to click "thanks" other than gratitude for the help because nothing can be gained from it by anybody.

To address the Facebook critique, the "thanks"-count does **not** need to be displayed publicly. Only privately to the author and answerer.

Comment: "12000 users likes this answer" Are we on Facebook?

Comment: I think this already exists... used to be called feedback, but is now the up/downvote button itself!

Comment: @HugoDozois The point I'm trying to make is that there is absolutely no incentive for 12000 people to press that button other than appreciation.

Comment: There actually is an anonymous feedback system already, but it does not translate into any direct display on posts.

Comment: @Paul if the user is not interested in making an account well too bad for him, he won't be able to give feedback.

Comment: @HugoDozois You are overlooking the fact that you need active participation too. Without it, you don't get the rep to vote up. I completely understand why that is. So rather than changing that, we could add a "thanks" button for visitors who feel helped with the discussed matter.

Comment: @Paul Well it need 15 reps, which means one question or answer. That is not really what I call "active" on the site. I don't think it would be that useful to add this functionality.

Comment: @AndrewBarber So where's that?

Comment: @Paul: it is (now) the arrows. There used to be buttons labeled "This post was helpful" (or something like that).

Comment: +1, even though the idea doesn't seem to very popular. I rather like the idea that anonymous users can express approval, even if they are unwilling to sign up.

Answer (score 9):

If you click the voting arrows it records positive or negative feedback on the post.

[image]

<sub>Also, comments which say "Thanks" are superfluous and noisy and hide the content which matters. Comments are considered the least useful form of giving back and are second class citizens. The best way to express gratitude is to give back to the community through high quality questions and answers (and edits, and votes).</sub>

Comment: I didn't know what ephemeral meant until I started moderating Stack Overflow.  Now I'm all-too-familiar with the word and exactly where it's applied in the site.

Comment: The content is already known to the authors, so it is not noise to them. And if you don't display the "thanks" publicly, it is not noise to the visitors either. The up-button needs an account and active participation in the community --- something completely unrelated to saying thanks.

Comment: @Paul: I don't wish to see "thanks" comments. There are voting arrows for just this purpose.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Okay, so you are saying you _are_ interested in hearing thanks from people, but _only_ if they are active on stackoverflow?

Comment: +1 for poorly drawn circle.

Comment: @H.Muster Don't be rude. It's obviously a [heart and an arrow](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrLYyjGwDAM2MGcuvjhKCsl6iW8Qvc9xNo0PtOpDl04SR5B4NLG2QyEA), to express love for the answer.

Comment: @dystroy Oops, my bad. Then it's actually +2 and a facebook like.

Comment: @dystroy I think they're a little confused, you don't express gratitude using the downvote arrow. Definitely a heart though. :/

Comment: @Paul I can only speak for myself, but I don't post because I'm interested in getting a load of "thanks" comments or meaningless "gratitude" votes; I do it because I enjoy doing so (and it gives me something to do during slow days at work). I think we should be encouraging people who come across SO via Google (or another search engine) to register and participate, rather than making it easier for them to interact with the site without doing so.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks. I think I was looking from the viewpoint of the visitor, not the author. As a visitor, the up button suggests that you can thank the author, while it seems to me now it is actually only a tool for people involved in the community. I thought that since apparently people _do_ appreciate the thanks (why else is that button there) then why not have a suitable alternative for outsiders who are not interested in asking/answering questions. But from all the -1 I see insiders are only interested in votes from insiders. Guess you're right the vote buttons show only to lure you in.

Comment: @Paul: you've conflated Thanks with Help. SO's job is to provide help to users. They express whether content is helpful or not with the voting arrows. Anonymous feedback expresses whether content is helpful to those outside of our community. Thanks are unnecessary, and I'd rather somebody contribute to the site with content if they feel the arrows just aren't enough.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Guess I shouldn't be telling you about micro-payments to say thanks then. "outsiders" are so unneccessary. Lol.

Comment: @Paul: if I want to be paid to write software, I'll do it at work. SO is not a job. You're only an outsider because you choose to be. If you'd like to contribute meaningfully to SO, you're given the option to, but please don't be surprised that our definition of "meaningful" is not the same as the rest of the Internets. It is necessarily different because it is required for the site to function like it does.

Comment: @sixlettervariables You're right, SO is doing a great job as it is. Many of my search queries end here. I just felt the need to thank somebody because their QA was very helpful to me. The arrows seemed to suggest I could do just that, but it turned out I can't (not without participating in the SO system myself that is). From all votes I grasp that a few more people are interested in the idea of anonymous appreciations, though most of you are not. The play on money was just a joke because you are so utterly pedantic about it. ;-)